# Jquery: How to insert an Jquery Mobile styled input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery mobile page where I want to insert some input texts when a button is pressed, and I've done this, however, the inputs are not Jquery Mobile styled, they're pure html styled... How can I do this ?

My code:

```
$("#add-unidade").on("click", function() {

    alert('entrou');

    var unidadeMedida = $("#select-unidadeMedida").val();
    var factor = $("#input-factor").val();
    var codigoBarras = $("#input-codigo-barras").val();
    var peso = $("#input-peso").val();

    var td1 = "<td><input type='text' disabled value='" + unidadeMedida + "' /></td>";
    var td2 = "<td><input type='text' disabled value='" + factor + "' /></td>";
    var td3 = "<td><input type='text' disabled value='" + codigoBarras + "' /></td>";
    var td4 = "<td><input type='text' disabled value='" + peso + "' /></td>";

    $("<tr>" + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4 + "</tr>").insertBefore("#formulario-unidades");

});
```

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamically added `input`, should be enhanced/initialized manually using `.textinput()`, in spite of its' *type*.

This works on all jQuery Mobile versions.

```
var input = $('<input type="text" placeholder="dynamic" />');
$("target_div").append(input);
$("[type=text]").textinput();
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uSzFL/)**